# The minor relation on infinite graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-graphs

The minor relation is defined in 1.7, GTM173.
The question is from the exercise 1.24
We already know that the minor relation defines a partial ordering on finite graphs.
Is it true for infinite graphs?

Comment: Can't we think of two distinct graphs which are each other's minors?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Intuitively I feel it is not true but I cannot construct a counterexample. Could you please show me one?

Comment: Please include more of the relevant definitions. It is very good that your provide references, but in addition the information should be in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very intuitive!